# PHP call_user_func_array - get the WHOLE array inside a function

Tags: php, class, content-management

I am trying to create a content management system with SEO friendly URLs .. My problem is, that with htaccess I have made my URLs passed through `$_GET['url']`.

To get the arguments for "call_user_func_array" I am just exploding `$_GET['url']` by `/`

I am allowing my users to create shorttag to the SEO-friendly URLS *WITH* slash (`/`) and therefore their shorttag will sometimes be passed as more arguments. Is there a way to collect all the arguments again inside the call class/function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$args = func_get_args();
```

will give you an array of all arguments passed into the function. That's actually undoing what you've done by using `call_user_func_array()`;

Comment: Hehe - why haven't I found that myself? Well doesn't really matter - you saved my day :-)

Answer (score 2):

Option 1 (passing array(array) to `call_user_func_array`):

```
$urls = explode('/', $_GET['url']);

// note that $urls already was an array
call_user_func_array(array('ClassName', 'MethodName'), array($urls));

// inside class ClassName    
function MethodName($urls) { // $urls is passed as array

}
```

Option 2 (using `func_get_args`):

```
$urls = explode('/', $_GET['url']);

// pass the array itself as argument, each split is new function argument
call_user_func_array(array('ClassName', 'MethodName'), $urls);

// inside class ClassName
function MethodName() { // this function has many arguments

    $urls = func_get_args(); // gets all arguments into array
}
```

Option 3 (using `call_user_func` instead of `call_user_func_array`):

```
$urls = explode('/', $_GET['url']);

// pass the array itself as argument
call_user_func(array('ClassName', 'MethodName'), $urls);

// inside class ClassName
function MethodName($urls) { // call_user_func will pass any argument on directly

}
```

Perhaps option 3 is the most appropriate for you. However you are limited in extensability when you want to add more arguments to function, but this is also true for option 2.

Comment: Well - I am doing this:

$url = explode('/', $_GET['url']);
call_user_func_array( array('ClassName', 'MethodName'), $urls );

and then I get the arguments as this:

function test($arg1, $arg2, $arg3 [...] $argn)
{

}

Comment: ... Which is probably as your option 2!

Comment: edited accordingly. But you should also consider the other options. As combining `call_user_func_array` AND `func_get_args` seems bad behaviour to me. Changing to option 3 is really easy.

Comment: I know - the problem is, that I am using the array-version in any other class than the pages-class.. Which means, that it is a work-around. Changing to option 3 would make me have to create another external helper-function which made the "$urls"-string converted to an array :-)